# How to calculate the distance using latitude and longitude when my data is in excel with source and destination data?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below data in excel for which i need the distance to be calculated using python.

i/p :

```
Source   lat1    lon1   Destination   lat2   lon2
A1      41.66   -2.21      B1        40.62  -2.16
A2      43.92   -4.76      B2        63.99  -7.17
A3      40.56   -1.17      B3        47.03  -5.11
A4      45.20   -6.77      B4        41.64  -6.18
A5      54.66   -3.07      B5        48.34  -4.41
A6      49.92   -1.14      B6        34.63   0.33
A7      50.05   -4.29      B7        45.49  -0.68
A8      51.69   -3.90      B8        56.13  -1.14
A9      53.05   -2.76      B9        27.89  -5.63
A10     60.06    0.36      B10       36.03  -2.16
A11     30.55   -1.57      B11       28.56  -3.81
```

Desired o/p:

```
Source   lat1    lon1   Destination       lat2   lon2    Distance
  A1    41.66   -2.21      B1            40.62  -2.16   115.6404811
  A2    43.92   -4.76      B2            63.99  -7.17   2235.355382
  A3    40.56   -1.17      B3            47.03  -5.11   785.070477
  A4    45.2    -6.77      B4            41.64  -6.18   398.4394688
  A5    54.66   -3.07      B5            48.34  -4.41   708.3334745
  A6    49.92   -1.14      B6            34.63  0.33    1703.22874
  A7    50.05   -4.29      B7            45.49  -0.68   573.8040788
  A8    51.69   -3.9       B8            56.13  -1.14   525.3010398
  A9    53.05   -2.76      B9            27.89  -5.63   2805.741242
  A10   60.06   0.36       B10           36.03  -2.16   2676.308887
  A11   30.55   -1.57      B11           28.56  -3.81   309.4651911
```

I am using the below haversine formula to get the distance output in excel.

```
Code :

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("df.xlsx")

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371):

if to_radians:
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
    np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2
return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

df['dist'] = \
         haversine(df.lat1.shift(), df.lon1.shift(), df.lat2.shift(), df.lon2.shift())
df.to_excel("df_output.xlsx", index = False)`
```

*Although I am getting the required results but it is shifted to one place down as shown below:

generated o/p with the above code:

```
Source   lat1    lon1   Destination       lat2   lon2    Distance
  A1    41.66   -2.21      B1            40.62  -2.16   
  A2    43.92   -4.76      B2            63.99  -7.17   115.6404811
  A3    40.56   -1.17      B3            47.03  -5.11   2235.355382
  A4    45.2    -6.77      B4            41.64  -6.18   785.070477
  A5    54.66   -3.07      B5            48.34  -4.41   398.4394688
  A6    49.92   -1.14      B6            34.63  0.33    708.3334745
  A7    50.05   -4.29      B7            45.49  -0.68   1703.22874
  A8    51.69   -3.9       B8            56.13  -1.14   573.8040788
  A9    53.05   -2.76      B9            27.89  -5.63   525.3010398
  A10   60.06   0.36       B10           36.03  -2.16   2805.741242
  A11   30.55   -1.57      B11           28.56  -3.81   2676.308887
```

Please help me to get the right code.

Thanks in advance :)

Kindly help somebody plzzzzz :)

Comment: please provide some code your are using. And provide some sample data, and edit your display message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in place of older one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("df_output.xlsx")

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371):

    if to_radians:
        lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2
    return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

df['dist'] = haversine(df['lat1'], df['lon1'], df['lat2'], df['lon2'])
df.to_excel("df_output.xlsx", index = False)
```

This will help you...

Comment: However just removing .shift() also worked. Thanks a lot :)